# What is the appropriate design pattern for the following situation?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

As an exercise I am working on a simple drawing app for the iPad.
I am using `UISplitView`, with the drawing view as the detail view. In the master view controller I present (in a table view) a list of the shapes drawn so far.

The user can edit or delete any shape from the master view controller, and also select and edit a shape by touching it in the detail view controller.

To notify each of the view controllers of the changes made by the other, I thought of using delegates, but I am not sure if this is the right pattern to use.

First, as I understand it, delegates are supposed to be used when a certain object encounters an event which they don't know how to handle. in that case they pass all the information to the delegate and let it handle the event. This is not the case here since both view controllers need to do something with the information. Using delegates here can cause code repetition.

Another reason I am thinking not to use delegates is that in the future I might want other view controllers to get the information of changes in the drawing. I can use multiple delegates (is it good practice in general?) but I'm not sure this is a good solution either.

Are there other solutions I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, I think delegates might be the right pattern to use here - you don't necessarily delegate *only* when you can't handle an event (though that *might* be one situation where you would delegate).

Instead, consider delegates a way of getting information to or from another object, when you simply don't know what that object might be. For example, Apple uses the delegate pattern when working with UITableViews; in that delegate protocol, the table view knows perfectly well what to do in each situation, but still notifies your code when certain actions are about to happen. I think that's an excellent parallel for your situation. (Note that a parallel to your question's assumptions also exists, in the UITableView "data source," where the table view does require some bits of information.)

Another technology you could consider using, if you're really dead-set against delegates, would be to use notifications. You can have each controller subscribe to particular notifications, then have your shape (or detail view controller) post instances of NSNotification when observable changes happen. That way, you still get to handle events happening in a different controller, but without needing to maintain a delegate list.

As for code duplication, just consider refactoring as you start encountering situations where you would duplicate; maybe you should design a single delegate or notification subscriber object for the common code, then only do class-specific things in each of the other controllers?